# Can't loot Rivet Gun from first Rosie in BioShock Remastered

Tags: bioshock

I have four weapons equipped at the moment: wrench, pistol, machine gun, and shotgun. Now I've killed the first Rosie Big Daddy, and it dropped its Rivet Gun. When I point at the Rivet Gun as in the screenshot its name is displayed suggesting it's a recognized object that might possibly be looted, and from what I've read that should be the case.

[image]

However, when I press E (or any other key) nothing seems to happen, as if I can't interact with this object at all.

What's going on? Can I actually loot this item now? Do I have too many (4) weapons equipped at the same time? Can I drop some to pick up this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wiki](https://bioshock.fandom.com/wiki/Rivet_Gun#BioShock) says:

> Because of its massive size and weight, the Rivet Gun cannot be wielded by a human such as Jack.

---

Perhaps you looted it already and just didn't notice? Or do you have to unlock U-Invents before you can loot it, since its primary items are crafting components?

[Wiki](https://bioshock.fandom.com/wiki/U-Invent) says:

> Starting with Arcadia, the player begins finding various new items when looting and searching, as well as finding the first U-Invent machine for using these items.

I assume the phenomenon you experienced is what it's trying to say. "Certain new container types and loot are unlocked."

Comment: Oh alright, I don't know how I missed that part. I thought I could pick up and use the actual gun. Guess not.

Comment: @yannbane I recently started playing and I couldn't pick up the rivet gun.